# Characterization of Fourier Series of Compactly Supported Functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I was wondering if there is any characterization of compactly supported functions by their Fourier series, that is, a counterpart of the Paley-Wiener Theorem for Fourier series.
More precisely, if $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is a function defined on the closed interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ with Fourier series $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=-\infty}$, are there any sufficient and necessary conditions for $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=-\infty}$ to make $f$ supported inside $(-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: Not really. But $\sum_n a_n \frac{\sin(z/2-\pi n)}{z-2\pi n}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ so you can check if it is $O(e^{r |\Im(z)|})$

Comment: @reuns Thank you. Why is this function the Fourier transform of $f$?